# Import Excel into Access – Column Title has special character

Tags: excel, ms-access

Is there a Access script that will edit an Excel title and import into Access? Each week I get Excel files from all of our buyers (about 200 Excel files) I already have a script in Access to import and combine all of these files. Right now I’m only importing column A-T. There are two other columns that my company now wants me to import and track the data. The issue is one of the titles in these new columns has a period in it (ex: Inv. Impact). I keep getting errors when trying to import which I now realize Access doesn’t like periods in the title.

Is there a script I can write to change the Title of all these files in Access or Import and edit the title? There are almost 200 files so I don’t have time to open and edit each file before importing.

Comment: You mean header I guess. Do you really need to import headers?

Comment: I just tested this. Import to new table worked. It's the Append that fails.  Looks like a programming flaw by MS to me. Yes, code could open and manipulate Excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, code can open and manipulate Excel and do Find/Replace. I used macro recorder in Workbook to generate some code and adapt in Access VBA procedure. Very simple example:

```
Sub FixHeader()
Dim xclApp As Excel.Application, xclWB As Excel.Workbook
Set xclApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xclWB = xclApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\June\Book1.xlsx")
xclWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
xclWB.Close True
xclApp.Quit
End Sub
```